# True or false? if $f:X\to \mathbb{R}$ is linear on normed space $X$ with closed graph, then $f$ is bounded.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

> True or false? if $f:X\to \mathbb{R}$ is linear on normed  space $X$ with closed graph, then $f$ is bounded.

If space $X$ was Banach, we could apply the closed graph theorem (since the space of reals is also Banach in the standard norm). Since we have no such information, we may not apply the theorem. On the other hand, this a special case, so
the proposition may hold.

One could note that if $f$ is not identically zero, then it is onto $\mathbb{R}$, but i am not sure if this is useful.

Any help is welcomed.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I posted a proof, for sake of completeness.

Answer (score 1):

Following the ideas in the link by @Ningxin we provide a proof that the answer is affirmative:
since $f$ is linear functional, it is enough to prove that $\mathrm{Ker}(f)$ is closed. Let $(x_n) \subset   \mathrm{Ker}(f)$ such that
$x_n \to x\in X$. Then $((x_n,0_X))\subset \mathrm{Gr}(f)$ and
$(x_n,0)\to (x,0)$, so $(x,0)\in \mathrm{Gr}(f)~\iff ~f(x)=0~\iff ~x\in  \mathrm{Ker}(f)$, since $\mathrm{Gr}(f)$ is closed, as wanted.